# Sharing ArrayList through Content Provider

Tags: android, arraylist, android-contentprovider

I have ArrayList in App1 and the database in App2. I want to store the values of Arraylist in database with the help of content provider.

I have the idea of how to get data from database through content provider. But I am unable to pass the Arraylist value through Content Provider. Can any one guide me?

Comment: can to explain how to do it?

Comment: just return MatrixCursor object in ContentProvider.query() method

Comment: I solved the problem by ContentResolver.insert();